# slds-notify test error

Tags: slds

why am I getting test failures for "slds-notify"

```
1) Element:
Tag: div
Classes: slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-alert_warning

Violation List:
1.1) Consider removing `slds-notify`, or updating to a slds classes with corresponding value
```

when the use of this is all over the documentation, and what is supposed to replace it, and where is that information.

See this for proof: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/alert/

Comment: Please take some time to read our [Code of Conduct](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/conduct). I completely understand your frustration, but neither rants nor attacks against helpful participants in this community are acceptable here.

Comment: In the interest of knowledge preservation, I kindly ask that nobody delete this post whilst I get this resolved. I think it's worth having, even if the original text was combative.

Answer (score 4):

`slds-notify` no longer does anything; it has been deprecated. If you scroll down to the [Overview of CSS Classes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/alert/#CSS-Class-Overview), you'll see that `slds-notify` is not listed. Anything not listed isn't officially part of the spec, as far as I'm aware.

Here's an [example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Csg0HCQQ6GiefQqMCSU6/src/app.html) comparing with and without this class. There is no difference.

Comment: @whatthehell Well, I have no team that can do this, as I'm not a salesforce.com employee. I know a few people though, maybe I can get things sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

@whattheh*ll - thank you for catching this! I'm on the team that maintains this, and I have updated the validator to allow this (deprecated but still present) classname. Those changes should be going out soon, so hopefully you won't have to wait too long for them to make their way into your org.

(And thank you for your continued help, @sfdcfox!)

Comment: it's not so much that it fails on deprecation that's the issue; that actually makes sense. it's an issue that it's used in sample code all over the place without making any kind of noticeable message anywhere that it's deprecated.  That's what's frustrating. Thanks for making our lives easier in anyway you can.

Comment: @whattheh*ll - agreed, it just seems to have fallen through the cracks at some point. The validator is turning up more things like this for us, so hopefully over time we'll find them all!